# How do I copy emails out of corrupted pst file?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, pst

I accidentally overwrote a pst file.  Pst file records show no files in them; and no ability to recover from within outlook. I can find the emails by doing searches in windows.  But scan pst.exe, recover my files, and Pareto have not been able to find them.

How can I copy the emails to a new pst file?

Comment: You say that you can find the emails in a Windows search, if you click on one of them, does the actual email come up or error out?

Comment: When you say you "overwrote" you pst file, are you assuming that because you don't see your emails or do you know for a fact it was overwritten? How did you overwrite it?

Comment: try shadow copy? it says you have win7. is that even an option?

Comment: @Lisa: what size is the new PST file? Right click on it and click on Properties.

Answer (score 1):

**Previous Versions if you're using Win7 or above**

> Previous versions are either copies of files and folders created by Windows Backup or copies of files and folders that Windows automatically saves as part of a restore point. You can use previous versions to restore files and folders that you accidentally modified or deleted, or that were damaged. Depending on the type of file or folder, you can open, save to a different location, or restore a previous version.

Right click the file or folder in question and select properties, Check the Previous Version Tab.

[image: PreviousVersions]

See if you can restore a previous version. Good Luck, hopefully this works.

Comment: Mind posting instructions, remembering that not everyone on here knows exactly where that is or what conditions need to be met for opening the Shadow Copies property window?

Comment: +1 for previous version. First place to look if you've got a serious problem like (what sounds like) a PST file overwritten by another.